# three fractions between π and 22/7

Tags: fractions, pi

three fractions between π and 22/7

π=355/113 =3.14159
22/7=3.1428

using a/b
355/113<22/7
then a+b/c+d
1)
355+22/113+7 =**377/120**~ 3.14166
2)
377+22/12+7 =**399/127**~3.14173
3)
399+22/127+7 =**421/134**~3.14179

is the method correct?!

Comment: $\pi$ is not $355/113$ though that is a good approximation.  Are you looking for approximations with "small" denominator?  If not, you can just look up the decimal expansion of $\pi$ and easily come up with $3$ examples, or $33$.

Comment: If you want to make a new line, either press enter twice, or make two spaces before pressing enter. I did it for you.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html